# Powershell - How to get the Output without the VariableValue when using WMIC

Tags: powershell, wmic

Good Afternoon,
I trust this finds you all very well.

I am learning powershell and i will really appreciate if someone could please help me with the following : i am not able to get only the output when using the following wmic cmd:

```
wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
```

This is what i am getting from that line:

```
PS C:\_Admin_RPC> wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy  

2
```

I have tried many thing but it is not working, i would be grateful if someone could please help me.

What i am planing to do is to save the value (2) in a variable and then use write-output to return $true if the value is the one that i am looking for.

Thank you and best regards.

Peace

Comment: `get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | % DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy`

Comment: THank you very much Jason for taking your time to help me. THis really works as well. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with PowerShell its always better to use the native PowerShell cmdlets or .NET Classes, simply because you get objects back instead of string values. This makes it alot easier to access certain values, may provide methods for further processing etc.

So back to your question, in principle you could do:

wmic in this case returns a array of strings, the value you are looking for is the 3rd element:

```
#get the value
(wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy)[2]

#get the value and store it in a variable
$value = (wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy)[2]
```

As js2010 already has pointed out on PowerShell there is the cmdlet `get-wmiobject` which is the equivalent to wmic. But this one got already replaced by `get-cimInstance`. So the PowerShell way is:

```
#Get all properties from class
$value = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem

#Display whole object
$value | fl *

#Access specific value
$value.'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy'

#For further optimization query only attributes needed instead of all
$value = Get-CimInstance -query "Select DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy from win32_operatingsystem"
$value.'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy'
```

You want `true` or `false` back if the property has the expected value. So we do not need to store that value, we can simply query if the expected value is set or not and then return `true` or `false`:

```
#Query for DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy = 2 and return true or false 
If (Get-CimInstance -query "Select DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy from win32_operatingsystem where DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy = 2"){
    #output on screen only
    write-host $true
}
Else {
    #output on screen only
    write-host $false
}
```

If you also want to know which value is set, you can do:

```
#Query for DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy, create object and write csv
$obj = Get-CimInstance -query "Select DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy from win32_operatingsystem"
If ($obj.'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy' -eq 2){
    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy' = $obj.'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy'
        'isExpectedValue' = $true
    }
}
Else {
    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy' = $obj.'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy'
        'isExpectedValue' = $false
    }
}
#write result to disk as csv
$result | export-csv [path] -Delimiter ";" -Encoding:utf8 -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Toni, I am more than grateful for your kind and detailed answer. I can see that all your explanations were given with love, it even makes me cry (overcome with emotions)... Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this to me, I am sure that it will help others. Have a wonderful day, an excellent week, and a very happy life. Sincerely and respectfully, your  #1 fan. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both js2010 and Toni answered my questions.

Nevertheless, the best answer was Toni's since he took into consideration my requests and took them to another level with his explanations.

At the end this is the solution that i am using based on the scenario that i am facing:

```
$value = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object -Property 'DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy'

$value = $value.DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy

if($value -eq 1){
    Write-Output $true
}
```

Thank you very much guys for your help and support.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in wmic you can do in powershell.

WMIC wmi class aliases:

(or in powershell "get-wmiobject -n root\cli msft_clialias", since alias itself is a wmi class alias)

I sorted them.  These are probably the most useful wmi classes (aside from win32_userprofile).

```
wmic alias get friendlyname,target

FriendlyName         Target
Alias                Select * from Msft_CliAlias
BIOS                 Select * from Win32_BIOS
BaseBoard            Select * from Win32_BaseBoard
BootConfig           Select * from Win32_BootConfiguration
CDROM                Select * from Win32_CDROMDrive
CPU                  Select * from WIN32_PROCESSOR
CSProduct            Select * from Win32_ComputerSystemProduct
ComputerSystem       Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
DCOMAPP              Select * from WIN32_DCOMApplication
DESKTOP              Select * from WIN32_DESKTOP
DMAChannel           Select * from Win32_DMAChannel
DataFile             Select * from CIM_DataFile
DesktopMonitor       Select * from WIN32_DESKTOPMONITOR
DeviceMemoryAddress  Select * from Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress
DiskDrive            Select * from Win32_DiskDrive
DiskQuota            Select * from Win32_DiskQuota
Environment          Select * from Win32_Environment
FSDir                Select * from Win32_Directory
Group                Select * from Win32_Group
IDECONTROLLER        Select * from Win32_IDEController
IRQ                  Select * from Win32_IRQResource
Job                  Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob
LOGON                Select * from Win32_LogonSession
LoadOrder            Select * from Win32_LoadOrderGroup
LogicalDisk          Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk
MEMCACHE             Select * from WIN32_CACHEMEMORY
MemPhysical          Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray
MemoryChip           Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory
NIC                  Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter
NICConfig            Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
NTDOMAIN             Select * from Win32_NTDomain
NTEvent              Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent
NTEventLog           Select * from Win32_NTEventlogFile
NetClient            Select * from WIN32_NetworkClient
NetLogin             Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
NetProtocol          Select * from Win32_NetworkProtocol
NetUse               Select * from Win32_NetworkConnection
OS                   Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem
OnBoardDevice        Select * from Win32_OnBoardDevice
PageFile             Select * from Win32_PageFileUsage
PageFileSet          Select * from Win32_PageFileSetting
Partition            Select * from Win32_DiskPartition
Port                 Select * from Win32_PortResource
PortConnector        Select * from Win32_PortConnector
PrintJob             Select * from Win32_PrintJob
Printer              Select * from Win32_Printer
PrinterConfig        Select * from Win32_PrinterConfiguration
Process              Select * from Win32_Process
Product              Select * from Win32_Product
QFE                  Select * from Win32_QuickFixEngineering
QuotaSetting         Select * from Win32_QuotaSetting
RDAccount            Select * from Win32_TSAccount
RDNIC                Select * from Win32_TSNetworkAdapterSetting
RDPermissions        Select * from Win32_TSPermissionsSetting
RDToggle             Select * from Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
RecoverOS            Select * from Win32_OSRecoveryConfiguration
Registry             Select * from Win32_Registry
SCSICONTROLLER       Select * from Win32_SCSIController
Server               Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Server
Service              Select * from Win32_Service
ShadowCopy           Select * from Win32_ShadowCopy
ShadowStorage        Select * from Win32_ShadowStorage
Share                Select * from Win32_Share
SoftwareElement      Select * from Win32_SoftwareElement
SoftwareFeature      Select * from Win32_SoftwareFeature
SoundDev             Select * from WIN32_SoundDevice
Startup              Select * from Win32_StartupCommand
SysAccount           Select * from Win32_SystemAccount
SysDriver            Select * from Win32_SystemDriver
SystemEnclosure      Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure
SystemSlot           Select * from Win32_SystemSlot
TapeDrive            Select * from Win32_TapeDrive
Temperature          Select * from Win32_TemperatureProbe
TimeZone             Select * from Win32_TimeZone
UPS                  Select * from Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply
UserAccount          Select * from Win32_UserAccount
Voltage              Select * from Win32_VoltageProbe
Volume               Select * from Win32_Volume
VolumeQuotaSetting   Select * from Win32_VolumeQuotaSetting
VolumeUserQuota      Select * from Win32_VolumeUserQuota
WMISet               Select * from Win32_WMISetting
```

So OS is an alias for win32_operatingsystem.  % or foreach-object is one way to get the value of a property.

```
$value = get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | 
  % DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
```

Different namespace for the top three, and the bottom one is gone.

```
get-wmiobject -n Root\CIMV2\TerminalServices Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
get-wmiobject -n Root\CIMV2\TerminalServices Win32_TSAccount
get-wmiobject -n Root\CIMV2\TerminalServices Win32_TSPermissionsSetting

get-wmiobject Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply # Invalid class
```

Comment: Hi JS2010, I trust this finds you well. Thx u very much for coming back to my question and for complementing your previous answer with this one. I really appreciated everything that you have explained to me. Have a lovely day and take care.